# Reading the PDF properties/metadata in Python

Tags: python, pdf, metadata

How can I read the properties/metadata like Title, Author, Subject and Keywords stored on a PDF file using Python?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/):

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

fp = open('diveintopython.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)

print(doc.info)  # The "Info" metadata
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> [{'CreationDate': 'D:20040520151901-0500',
  'Creator': 'DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.52.2',
  'Keywords': 'Python, Dive Into Python, tutorial, object-oriented, programming, documentation, book, free',
  'Producer': 'htmldoc 1.8.23 Copyright 1997-2002 Easy Software Products, All Rights Reserved.',
  'Title': 'Dive Into Python'}]
```

For more info, look at this tutorial: [A lightweight XMP parser for extracting PDF metadata in Python](http://blog.matt-swain.com/post/25650072381/a-lightweight-xmp-parser-for-extracting-pdf-metadata-in).

Comment: A heads-up: the author of pdfminer says it's incompatible with Python   3, at least as of date of this post ([link](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/))

Comment: As of November 2013, the "PDFDocument class now takes a PDFParser object as an argument. PDFDocument.set_parser() and PDFParser.set_document() is removed."  So you can just do doc=PDFDocument(parser), and skip the calls to set_document, set_parser, and initialize.

Comment: @JSmyth The [PyPi Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pdfminer&submit=search) currently lists three working `pdfminer` forks that are compatible with Python 3. `pip search pdfminer`

Comment: @zero2cx thanks for the update. I personally settled on [pdfminer3k](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k/). Works well for my purposes. One has to read the API document in the repo though as the accepted here answer is not a valid API for pdfminer3k anymore.

Comment: There is now an official Python 3 fork of the project https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: Using `pdfminer.six `, for this paper https://z0ngqing.github.io/paper/nips-jiechuan18.pdf, I got an empty string for the title.

Answer (score 24):

As the maintainer of [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) I strongly recommend pypdf :-)

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("test.pdf")

# See what is there:
print(str(reader.metadata))

# Or just access specific values:
print(reader.metadata.creation_date)  # that is actually a datetime object!
```

Install using `pip install pypdf --upgrade`.

See also: [How to read/write metadata with pypdf](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html)

Comment: I tried @Rabash's answer and it gives me similar results. I think this is better becase  it gives better information about the creator. This code's creator output is 'Microsoft...' and Rabash's code gives me some encoded characters.

Answer (score 9):

[pikepdf](https://pypi.org/project/pikepdf/) provides an easy and reliable way to do this.

I tested this with a bunch of pdf files, and it seems there are two distinct ways to insert metadata when the PDF is created. Some are inserting `NUL` bytes and other gibberish. Pikepdf handles both well.

```
import pikepdf
p = pikepdf.Pdf.open(r'path/to/file.pdf')
str(p.docinfo['/Author'])  # mind the slash
```

This returns a string - if you wrapped it with `str`. Examples:

- `'Normal person'`
- `'ABC'`

Comparing with other options:

- [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer) - Not actively maintained
- [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) - active
- [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) - active (but still suggest you to use `easy_install`, a.o.)
- [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) - Active.
- [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) - was merged back into pypdf. `PyPDF2==3.0.0` and `pypdf==3.1.0` are essentially the same, but development continues in pypdf
- [Borb](https://borbpdf.com) - Active.

---

### Pdfminer.six:

`pip install pdfminer.six`

```
import pdfminer.pdfparser
import pdfminer.pdfdocument
h = open('path/to/file.pdf', 'rb')
p = pdfminer.pdfparser.PDFParser(h)
d = pdfminer.pdfparser.PDFDocument(p)
d.info[0]['Author']
```

This returns a binary string, including the non-decodable characters if they are present. Examples:

- `b'Normal person'`
- `b'\xfe\xff\x00A\x00B\x00C'` (ABC)

To convert to a string:

- `b'Normal person'.decode()` yields the string `'Normal person'`
- `b'\xfe\xff\x00A\x00B\x00C'.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').replace('\x00', '')` yields the string `'ABC'`

---

### pdfreader

`pip install pdfreader`

```
import pdfreader
h = open(r'path/to/file.pdf', 'rb')
d = pdfreader.PDFDocument(h)
d.metadata['Author']
```

This returns either the string with the requested information, or a string containing the hex representation of the data it found. This then also includes the same non-decodable characters. Examples:

- `'Normal person'`
- `'FEFF004100420043'` (ABC)

You would then first need to detect whether this is still 'encoded', which I think is quite a nuisance. The second can be made a sensible string by calling this ugly piece of code:

```
s = 'FEFF004100420043'
''.join([c for c in (chr(int(s[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)) if c.isascii()]).replace('\x00', '')
>>> 'ABC'
```

---

### Borb

`pip install borb`

```
import borb.pdf.pdf
h = open(r'path/to/file.pdf', 'rb')
d = borb.pdf.document.Document = borb.pdf.pdf.PDF.loads(h)
str(d.get_document_info().get_author())
```

This returns a string - if you wrapped it with `str`. Loading a sizeable PDF takes a long time. I had one PDF on which borb choked with a TypeError exception. See also the examples on [borb's dedicated example repo](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#31-extracting-meta-information).

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented this using [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/). Please see the sample code below. `pypdf` is maintained again since December 2022. The `PyPDF2` project was merged back into pypdf.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
pdf_toread = PdfReader(open("doc2.pdf", "rb"))
pdf_info = pdf_toread.metadata
print(str(pdf_info))
```

Output:

```
{'/Title': u'Microsoft Word - Agnico-Eagle - Complaint (00040197-2)', '/CreationDate': u"D:20111108111228-05'00'", '/Producer': u'Acrobat Distiller 10.0.0 (Windows)', '/ModDate': u"D:20111108112409-05'00'", '/Creator': u'PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2', '/Author': u'LdelPino'}
```

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3 and new pdfminer (pip install pdfminer3k):

```
import os
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFDocument

fp = open("foo.pdf", 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
parser.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(parser)
if len(doc.info) > 0:
    info = doc.info[0]
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](http://pdfreader.readthedocs.io/)
You can access document catalog Metadata like below:

```
   from pdfreader import PDFDocument    
   f = open("foo.pdf", 'rb')
   doc = PDFDocument(f)
   metadata = doc.root.Metadata
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can you please detail why the python market of PDF libraries needed another solution? Which shortcomings does it address ? Cheers!

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă As for me the best tool at the moment is *pdfminer* but it is very slow on big documents and not always good for parsing text data.