# Extract metadata for all documents in Clio

Tags: metadata, document, clio-api

Clio Service desk have pointed me in the direction of the API for extracting key document metadata such as doc ID, name, creation date, modified date.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Per the API Documentation](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#tag/Documents/operation/Document#index):

You can use the documents endpoint to request document information such as ID, created date, updated date, filename, and various other information related to the file being stored in CLIO:

```
"data": [
{
"id": 0,
"etag": "string",
"created_at": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
"updated_at": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
"deleted_at": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
"type": "Document",
"locked": true,
"name": "string",
"received_at": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
"filename": "string",
"size": 0,
"content_type": "string",
"parent": { },
"matter": {},
"contact": {},
"document_category": {},
"creator": {},
"latest_document_version": {},
"group": {},
"external_properties": [],
"document_versions": []
```

If you are trying to get to metadata contained within the file like a PDF or Word Document... The API doesn't have the ability.  However, the API could be used to retrieve the file, which could then be parsed via Python ([Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242017/how-to-extract-metadata-from-docx-file-using-python) [PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209214/reading-the-pdf-properties-metadata-in-python)), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493189/reading-pdf-metadata-in-php), etc.